# Edit a listview line on another page with textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to create a page an aspx page that allows me to modify the data of the listview row that are associated to a db, but I can't get the values.

I tried to do a query string

```
    protected void EditButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      int id = Convert.ToInt32(((Button)sender).Attributes["ID_Persona"]);
      Response.Redirect("http://localhost:60082/pages/Edit.aspx" + "? 
      ID_Persona=" + id);
    }
```

and to take the value on the page where I need it

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        TextBox1.Text = Request.QueryString.Get("ID_Persona").ToString();
        }
```

but I don't know how to display the line I want to edit in the textboxes.

this is the button that redirects to the edit page

```
    protected void EditButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     int id = Convert.ToInt32(((Button)sender).Attributes["ID_Persona"]);
     Response.Redirect("http://localhost:60082/pages/Edit.aspx" + "? 
     ID_Persona=" + id);
    }
```

this is the edit page

```
 public partial class Edit : System.Web.UI.Page
    { 
    string constr = 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnection"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox1.Text = Request.QueryString.Get("ID_Persona").ToString();

    }

    protected void CustomerUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomerUpdate();
    }
    private int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ID"]) ? int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]) : 0;
        }
    }
    private void CustomerUpdate()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Persona SET Nome=@Nome, Cognome=@Cognome,Email=@Email,CodiceFiscale=@CodiceFiscale WHERE ID=@ID", con))
            {

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Nome", TextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Cognome", TextBox15.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", TextBox20.Text);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CodiceFiscale",TextBox22.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", "");
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, false);
                Response.Redirect("Dash.aspx");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the question is tagged with C but since it uses C# it should be tagged C#...

Comment: I was wrong, I modified it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that

```
                if (queryy == "1")
                {
                    B2.Visible = false;
                    var connectionString = 
             ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnection"].ConnectionString;
                    string query = "SELECT ID,Nome,Cognome,Email,CodiceFiscale FROM 
                    Persona WHERE ID = @id";
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 
                            Request.QueryString.Get("ID_Persona"));
                            con.Open();
                            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                if (rdr.Read())
                                {

                                    TextBox1.Text = rdr["Nome"].ToString();
                                    TextBox15.Text = rdr["Cognome"].ToString();
                                    TextBox20.Text = rdr["Email"].ToString();
                                    TextBox22.Text = rdr["CodiceFiscale"].ToString();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you shuld make public the methods which sends the information like the query but i'm not sure that will work.

Comment: It already works because in the texbox1 it shows me the ID, but I want the name, surname etc.

Comment: you want  the Id, name, surname etc... in the same text box?

Comment: no no, each textbox its value (one for the name, one for the surname etc ..)